# Please explain the Weight Function

Tags: descriptive-statistics, weighted-data

I'm very new into statistics. And I need to find a statistical method to analyse a data set obtained from an experiment.

Since I don't have the right to include images I'll try to explain it. The experiment is an observation of times of completion of tasks (10 in total) by participants that used the stimulus for the first time. As you can imagine the summing up time of completion graph represents an exponential line, since user improves in efficiency with every task.

I want to count the average time of completion, but in order to leverage the very first/second tries (that gets ridiculously long) and get it to the value where the exponential line more or less stabilise (not sure it's a right word though) I was advised to use a weighing function, which I have no idea about. All I know that it helps to give importance to a certain part of the data and that it could be linear or exponential. I guess in my case of exponential dependance I need exponential weight function?

Could you please advise me on how to properly apply this Weight Function on my data.

Please do not hesitate to ask for any clarification.

Thank you good sirs!